# VLC UI Scaling Issue in Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: lubuntu, vlc, display-resolution, amd-graphics, scaling

In Lubuntu 18.04, I installed VLC via `apt install vlc`, but for some reason, the scaling of the interface is way off:

[image: Image 1]

The menus as well as the system tray icon are super pixelated and stretched too.

I have a regular 1080p screen, and no other applications I've tested so far have had any issues.

I have `radeon` graphics drivers installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add the line

```
QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0
```

to my /etc/environment file, and it works now.